# how to create a pam module?

Tags: linux, pam

Can anyone tell me about this...
I want to create a pam module similar to the login module in /etc/pam.d

Answer (score 15):

If you are looking for pam based face authentication during login, you need to write a module which does that for you and plug that in login configuration file at /etc/pam.d/login.

Before directly get into this, I would suggest you to write some simple module to understand the flow, working of PAM and configuration file like start playing with sshd pam configuration file and try to plug some sample pam module available. I found these article quite helpful :

http://aplawrence.com/Basics/understandingpam.html

https://www.packtpub.com/article/development-with-pluggable-authentication-modules-pam

FYI : Rohan Anil developed pam-face-authentication during GSOC08 under opensuse which is hosted at  code.google.com/p/pam-face-authentication/

Comment: First link does not give any idea on development of the module.

Answer (score 9):

Since the answer is really to long to be written here, I can link you my PAM tutorials:
[Write a Linux PAM module](https://web.archive.org/web/20190523222819/https://fedetask.com/write-linux-pam-module/) and
[Linux PAM Configuration tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20190420035810/https://fedetask.com/linx-pam-configuration-tutorial/)

Before starting writing the module I advise you to read the configuration tutorial first, in which you can learn what does the module do.

To sum up, a module is a shared object loaded by PAM when the application wants to authenticate. Every time the application triggers a "stage" (auth, account, session, password) the correspondent function is called in the module. Therefore, your module should provide the following functions:

```c
PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_authenticate(pam_handle_t *handle, int flags, int argc, const char **argv){
    /* In this function we will ask the username and the password with pam_get_user()
     * and pam_get_authtok(). We will then decide if the user is authenticated */
}

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_acct_mgmt(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
    /* In this function we check that the user is allowed in the system. We already know
     * that he's authenticated, but we could apply restrictions based on time of the day,
     * resources in the system etc. */
}

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_setcred(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
    /* We could have many more information of the user other then password and username.
     * These are the credentials. For example, a kerberos ticket. Here we establish those
     * and make them visible to the application */
}

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_open_session(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
    /* When the application wants to open a session, this function is called. Here we should
     * build the user environment (setting environment variables, mounting directories etc) */
}

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_close_session(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
    /* Here we destroy the environment we have created above */
}

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_chauthtok(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv){
    /* This function is called to change the authentication token. Here we should,
     * for example, change the user password with the new password */
}
```

In this functions you will use PAM functions to retrieve the username and the password from the application. This happens through a conversation function that must be defined in the application (see [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20190420073246/https://fedetask.com/writing-a-linux-pam-aware-application/)). At the end of every function, you must return a PAM return code that determines the result (for PAM error codes see [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/8329799/chap5.htm) and the module [writer documentation in general](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwij-fb0opjfAhWHLVAKHULyDlsQFjAAegQICRAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linux-pam.org%2FLinux-PAM-html%2FLinux-PAM_MWG.html&usg=AOvVaw3LcTvyA_9VK2CFimeDfcv9)).

Answer (score 3):

One of the best resources for authoring pam modules is the documentation
itself:

[The Linux-PAM Module Writers' Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20220516124114/http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_MWG.html)

However I agree with [@GG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164933/gg) in making sure you understand how PAM works first.