# how to create a simple pam application?

Tags: pam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to create a pam module??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841203/how-to-create-a-pam-module)

Please help me out. I want to create an application for login which uses face authentication...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841203/how-to-create-a-pam-module

Comment: "Simple" and "face recognition" don't go well together. What are you using for the recognition, OpenCV?

Comment: yes openCV.. At first i want to know how to make a simple pam application and then how to integrate face recognition in it..

Comment: @piskvor: why have u closed this question.. I need to find its answer..

Comment: Yes, I understand that you need the answer. However, your question amounts to little more than "I need *something*, help!" If you decide to repost, please be more specific: what platform is this (Linux?)? What have you tried so far? What worked? What worked differently than you expected? What didn't work? How is this different from what the documentation says? These will give you a better chance at a meaningful answer. Posting only "I need X" reads a bit like "...so I expect you people to do all the work for me." We can (probably) help you, but you need to show your effort.

Comment: @piskvor: really sorry for that.. I am using linux mint 10(julia)..  We have created an application using OpenCV which authorizes the user using face recognition.. Now  we want to integrate this with pam.. So that instead of the original login module(pam.d) the one which we intent to create, will be called..

Comment: @piskvor: "closed as exact duplicate" reading this sentence i got frustrated.. really sorry.. I am new to forums so i repeated the question forgetting that i have already asked it..