# Using my own python script to authenticate into my computer

Tags: python, linux, authentication, pam

I try to create a python script to check the password instead of my computer, So i use [python-pam](https://pypi.org/project/python-pam/) for that. The problem is that i don't know how i can use my script in the common-auth file.

I tried this:

```
auth    required                        /home/gamzer/test-python-pam.py
```

But it tells me this:

```
sudo: PAM unable to dlopen(/home/gamzer/test-python-pam.py): /home/gamzer/test-python-pam.py: invalid ELF header
```

Here's my script:

```
import pam
from getpass import getuser, getpass

if pam.authenticate(getuser(), getpass()):
        print 'ok'
else:
        print 'not ok'
```

Answer (score 2):

First off - you cannot use python code as a PAM module, it has to be compiled code that satisfies certain interface requirements. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4957047/1708913) for more info.

Also - what you are trying here seems circular, using PAM itself to implement PAM functionality.

Comment: maybe I can use a wrapper or a compiler of some sort in order to use python? this one seems to use python with pam https://github.com/Boltgolt/howdy

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to

1. use PAM to check a password in a python program that needs to verify a password, or
2. implement a new authentication method for the system to use?

In case #2, @dngrs is exactly right--you can't do it that way.

In case #1, you don't need anything in the `common-auth` file. Also, to check a password in your Python code, I think you need to create a PAM object, so it would look more like this:

```
import pam
from getpass import getuser, getpass

p = pam.pam()
if p.authenticate(getuser(), getpass()):
    print 'ok'
else:
    print 'not ok'
```

as shown in the [python-pam README](https://github.com/FirefighterBlu3/python-pam)

Comment: I'm in case #2. I'm trying to build a new authentication method when the session password is asked